# Nuget install: Is there way to pass credentials or key with this command?

Tags: installation, nuget, artifactory, nuget-package

I am trying to execute  the below command

```
nuget install <package name> -DirectDownload -version <version number> -OutputDirectory <local_path>
```

Since its a private Jfrog Artifactory instance, how can in pass my credentials(key)?

Answer (score 1):

NuGet requires that sensitive operations such as push and delete are authenticated with the server using an API key. The API key you should use is in the form of `username:password`, where the password can be either clear-text or encrypted.
Set your API key using the NuGet Command Line Interface:

```
nuget setapikey admin:password -Source Artifactory
```

For more info see the Artifactory [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/NuGet+Repositories#NuGetRepositories-NuGetAPIKeyAuthentication) about NuGet repositories